# An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1878486530-323938 (1541428280)

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have a requirement to create a screenflow on account object where  first screen shows two user choices 1. share Account and 2.Remove access

when running user selects "1.share account" Option flow creates an' Account Team Member' record after collecting appropriate data from the user through Screens.

When user selects "2. Remove access " option the flows shows a data table with the existing "Account Team Member" records related to that account, Inorder to achieve this i used a Get Records element in the flow that fetches "All Account Team Member" records, with condition AccountId = recordId(id Of the Account on which the flow is triggered), It is throwing error if a Partner user is running the flow but working fine if a  standard user runs the flow. Please help me with this issue.

I have posted this in community, there i got this Actual error from salesforce support team.
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: User.Title: alias not found: t_spn0_USER_CUSTOMIZATION"

But I am not getting where I am going wrong, could anyone please help me?